# Gradle in intellij log - Could not create an instance of Tooling API implementation using the specified Gradle distribution

Tags: java, gradle, intellij-idea, build.gradle

All my Gradle projects are not recognized suddenly in IntelliJ, and I am getting this message in the IntelliJ log:

> Could not create an instance of Tooling API implementation using the
>   specified Gradle distribution
>   'https://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-5.4.1-all.zip'.

The Gradle build in terminal still works.

I am using IntelliJ on Mac OS. Note that the same project works fine on other Windows machine.

I have this distribution in my Gradle wrapper:

```
distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-5.4.1-all.zip
```

I have already tried all the other manuals and:

1. to change the `distributionUrl` to another version (it has been downloaded but again same error message)
2. to download a working sample of other project from `start.spring.io` (also same error)
3. to uninstall Gradle, clean the whole folder in `~/.gradle`, and install Gradle again (still same error)
4. to uninstall the JDK, Gradle and IntelliJ, and reinstall them again.

I have also checked the IntelliJ logs and here is what I got there: http://ibb.co/cwDhy6F and http://ibb.co/D5Jv3cn

Comment: Try using different Gradle version in Settings (Preferences on macOS) | Build, Execution, Deployment | Build Tools | Gradle | *Use local Gradle distribution*. Does it help? try also re-install IDE from https://www.jetbrains.com/idea/download If you have antivirus/firewall try with it disabled or make sure that IDE [settings directories](https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/articles/206544519) IDE installation home and project files are excluded from the scan.

Comment: 1. Try using different Gradle version in Settings - didn't work .                                 
2. Try to re-install IDE again with + clearing all the intellij internal folders on mac - Configuration (idea.config.path): ~/Library/Preferences/<PRODUCT>
Caches (idea.system.path): ~/Library/Caches/<PRODUCT>
Plugins (idea.plugins.path): ~/Library/Application Support/<PRODUCT>
Logs (idea.log.path): ~/Library/Logs/<PRODUCT>
+ Clearing the trash + rm -R ~/.gradle (to clear gradle again) + invalid cach and restart on intellij

**--Unfortunately Both Didn't solved the issue**

Comment: Any other suggestions before i going to the most extreme option of formatting the computer :(